# Can't set dynamic image in ListView.builder in PDF Invoice in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am making flutter pdf invoice. For that I have dynamic List and I have to show dynamic image from list in pdf invoice. I can set image statically but not set dynamically(using index).

Hello all,

I am expecting a proper solution for that problem

Comment: can you include a sample snippet that will reproduce proper & specific issue. More about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this.
let's say myProducts is your dynamic list

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('KindaCode.com'),
        ),
        // implement the list view
        body: ListView.builder(
            // the number of items in the list
            itemCount: myProducts.length,

            // display each item of the product list
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Card(
                // In many cases, the key isn't mandatory
                key: ValueKey(myProducts[index]),
                margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 15),
                child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    child: Text(myProducts[index])),
              );
            }));
  }
```

Comment: Its not like that. I want to set dynamic image from dynamic list in pdf.addPage.